# Reactjs: Key undefined when accessed as a prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

Tools: Reactjs 0.14.0 Vanilla Flux

I need unique identifiers for 2 reasons:

1. [Child Reconciliation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#child-reconciliation)
2. [Keeping track of what child was clicked](http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/expose-component-functions.html)

So let's say I have a list of messages that looks like this:

```
[
    {
      id: 1241241234,  // <-----The unique id is kept here
      authorName: "Nick"
      text: "Hi!"
    },
    ...
]
```

And now I use a `Array.prototype.map()` to create ["ownee"](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#ownership) component (`MessageListItem`) inside of the owner component `MessageSection`

```
function getMessageListItem(message) {
    return (
        <MessageListItem key={message.id} message={message} />
    );
}

var MessageSection = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var messageListItems = this.state.messages.map(getMessageListItem);
        <div>
            {messageListItems }
        </div>
    }
});
```

But the `this.props.key` is undefined in the `MessageListItem` even though I know for a fact that is was defined when it was passed down.

```
var ConvoListItem = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        console.log(this.props.key); // Undefined
    }
});
```

I'm guessing there is a reason that React is not letting `key` be used as a prop.

Question:

If I can't use `key` as a prop, then what is the proper way to handle the duality need of keying and setting unique identifiers on a dynamic list of child elements that contain state?

Comment: React uses `key` internally, can you just use a different prop name?

Comment: Yes, something like 'key={message.id} myId={message.id}'

Comment: So just use the same id twice like @GrigoryKatkov suggests? If everybody agrees, I'll accept that as the answer :) Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is best to use id. Then in the eventHandler you can have event.target.id.

```js
function getMessageListItem(message) {

  return (
    <MessageListItem key={message.id} id={message.id} message={message}/>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 35):

key and ref aren't really 'props'. They're used internally by react and not passed to components as props. Consider passing it as a prop such as 'id'.

Answer (score 2):

As we already established in other answers that you can't use `key` since it isn't passed as a prop and instead used internally by react. Here is my 2 cents as an alternative:

Since you're passing the entire array of messages as a prop while creating the `<MessageListItem>` component, you don't necessarily need to pass another prop with `id`. You can simply use `{this.props.message.id}` whenever you need to use id.

Answer (score 0):

As you've discovered, the `key` property is consumed by React itself, not passed to the child component. It's what React uses to keep track of entries in arrays to avoid unnecessarily re-rendering them (both in terms of calling their `render` and reconciling with the DOM).

Unfortunately, that means if you also want to use it in the child, you have to pass it twice. In your code, you **already are** passing it twice (once as `key`, one as part of `message`). So you can keep your current JSX, just use `id` from `message` in the child:

```
var MessageListItem = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        console.log(this.props.message.id);
//                             ^^^^^^^^^^^−−−−− Has the value
    }
});
```

More:

- [Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)
- [Why keys are necessary](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#recursing-on-children) (linked from the above)
- [Special props warning](https://reactjs.org/warnings/special-props.html) - which tells us that `key` and `ref` are special props not passed on to the child component